# Why doesn't this "Freeze" the string?

Tags: ruby, string, object, freeze

I have the made this:

```
a = 1280
b = 900
a.freeze
b.freeze
a = 800
b = 600
puts a
puts b
```

and it results in:

```
800
600
```

but the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze) said, it should raise me an error if I try to modify an existing object which is frozen. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assignment does not modify the object, but it makes the variable reference another object; so `freeze` does not apply here.

Comment: ok that was super fast. So what can i do to freeze my values after they assigned once? I want to set it to a custom value (gets) and freeze them after the user select "SAVE" from a menue i give.

Comment: @user3797760, Once it's frozen, operations that modify the object like `String#<<`, `String#[]=`, `String#delete!`, `String#gsub!`, .. will be prohibited, but assignment.

Comment: @user3797760, `So what can i do to freeze my values after they assigned once?` Write code that doesn't assign to the those variables again.

Comment: If you want your variables to be constant, you should use constants (i.e. identifiers starting with an uppercase letter) not variables (starting with a lowercase) letter. Note that constants can actually be re-assigned in Ruby, so they aren't actually constant, but at least they generate a warning.